# Getting ERR_BAD_RESPONSE error on hosted website while it is working fine on localhost

Tags: node.js, api, next.js

I have a next js website which uses openai api to take prompt and generate response, the problem I am facing is that it is working fine on localhost but when I host the website it is giving me this error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/semWq.png)

here is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const {Configuration, OpenAIApi} = require('openai')
const cors = require('cors'); // import cors middleware

const app = express();

app.use(cors()); // enable cors for all origins

app.use(express.json());


export default async function handler(req, res) {

  const {prompt,
    apiKey
  
  } = req.body;
const API_KEY = apiKey
const config = new Configuration({
  apiKey: API_KEY
})
const openai = new OpenAIApi(config)



const completion = await openai.createCompletion({
    model: 'text-davinci-003',
    max_tokens: 1024,
    temperature:0,
    prompt: `${prompt}
  `

})


res.send(completion.data.choices[0].text);
}
```

This is how I am posting data:

```
const generateJobProposal = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    
    axios
    .post(`/api/prompt`, {prompt,
    apiKey
  })
    .then((res)=>{
      setResponse(res.data);
      
      


};
```

Keep in mind that the code is working 100% fine on localhost